# How to isolate a div in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, browser

Is there a way of to have Firefox display only a given element on a page, hiding everything else?

Ideally I'd like to highlight the element (such as a `div`) in the Console (*Inspect element* menu option) and then use a command or extension to show only that element (with styles, scripts and so on from the page still applied).

I know that printwhatyoulike.com does something similar but it had trouble dealing with scripts on a page, as well as modifying formatting, so it's not suitable to me.

Comment: AdBlock Plus can be used to block specific elements on a page. You will be required to block almost everything, but once done, it shuold result in what you're after. Keep in mind that you have to specify that webpage, or adblock will block it on every website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you *can* do this in plain Firefox:

1. Navigate to the element you want
2. Right-click on the element, select "Inspect element". This brings up the developer console.
3. The relevant HTML element should already be selected for you, but you can browse through the source to capture the exact area you want - usually a few level above, and made easy because of highlighting.
4. Right click on the element in the HTML source and select "Screenshot element".